# Want to hide menu by clicking outside the menu element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide my menu by clicking on any part of the web, rather than the menu button here is de js:

```
mobile_nav.click(function(){

        if (desktop_nav.hasClass("js-opened")) {
            desktop_nav.slideUp("slow", "easeOutExpo").removeClass("js-opened");
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }
        else {
            desktop_nav.slideDown("slow", "easeOutQuart").addClass("js-opened");
            $(this).addClass("active");

            // Fix for responsive menu
            if ($(".main-nav").hasClass("not-top")){
                $(window).scrollTo(".main-nav", "slow"); 
            }

        }

    });
```

and the HTML

```
                <div class="inner-nav desktop-nav">
                    <ul class="clearlist scroll-nav local-scroll">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html" style="font-weight: bold;">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="help.html" style="font-weight: bold;">Who we help</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="mn-has-sub" style="font-weight: bold;">Services <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>

                           <!-- Sub -->
                            <ul class="mn-sub to-left" style="background: white !important;">

                                <li>
                                    <a href="recovery.html" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;">Recovery Coaching</a>

                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="non-addict.html" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;">Coaching and Support for Loved Ones</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="couples.html" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;">Family and Couples Coaching</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="interventions.html" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;">Interventions</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="liferecovery.html" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;">LIFE COACHING IN RECOVERY</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="divorce.html" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;">Separation and Divorce Coaching</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="therapy.html" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;">Therapy</a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                            <!-- End Sub -->

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="about.html" style="font-weight: bold;">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact" style="font-weight: bold;">WORK WITH US</a></li>
                        <li><a href="faq.html" style="font-weight: bold;">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog.html" style="font-weight: bold;">Blog</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
```

I wanted a simple code that I can put in that js, because I tried to put in the head tag in the index but its not working, any ideas? I have the CSS too but I think its not relevant at this point, the site is:
http://www.familyaddictionspecialist.com/test/

Comment: when the site goes mobile, the menu class is mobile-nav

Comment: using jquery, when the menu is opened you can add .focus to the menu item, then you can add an .blur event handler to close the menu once the user clicks away from it.

Comment: @Clint so how the code should looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var $menu = $('.main-nav');

    $('mobile_nav').click(function () {
      $menu.toggle();
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
       if (!$menu.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
       && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
       {
                    desktop_nav.slideUp("slow", "easeOutExpo").removeClass("js-opened");
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
      }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
var thatMenu = $('.thatMenu');

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
 if (!thatMenu.is(e.target) && thatMenu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
  thatMenu.hide();
 }
});
```

Comment: I tried but isnt working..also I put my menu class :(

Comment: The only think I can think of is did you put it in document ready function?

Comment: Or just replace 'thatMenu' with '$('.thatMenu')' by yourself and in that if condition put there this '$(this)'

Answer (score 0):

untested but looking at your code, this could work.
the idea is that there is an event handler on the body of the page that when it fires, it checks to make sure you haven't clicked on any child of js-opened, and closes the element with class js-opened.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").click(function(event) {
     if ($(event.target).parents('div').hasClass("js-opened") === false){
        console.log('closed menu');
        $('.js-opened').slideUp("slow", "easeOutExpo").removeClass("js-opened");          
       }      
    });
  });
```

Comment: This code close my menu after opened...doesnt let me click somewhere outside the menu to close :( thats what I need